# Replace missing values from list in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this

```
                       A           B

2018-02-01 00:00:00 5.592860    2.789900
2018-02-01 00:15:00 5.288981    2.054017
2018-02-01 00:30:00 5.319665    2.232686
2018-02-01 00:45:00 5.198657    2.236154
2018-02-01 01:00:00 5.018134    2.064312
```

The Column A will not have any missing values, but column B will be having.

I have another list like this of length 12 named forecasts

```
[0.09545173 0.09946214 0.10596157 0.12075519 0.14446978 0.16848372
  0.20479251 0.23742175 0.26723814 0.29389328 0.30628437 0.3140854 ]
```

I want to loop through each row in the dataframe and check whether next 12 rows have any `nan`. If `nan` is present, replace that value from the corresponding index from the list.

If the 2nd row from the current index is `nan` then replace that `nan` by `forecasts[2]`

To make things more clear,

I will have a dataframe with data like I said the question. There may be misses in the column B but not A. I will have a list of 12 location for each timestamp. The list being named forecast will have the forecasted value of present timestamp in forecasts[0] and 11th timestamp from now in forecast[11]. I want to loop though each timestamp in the dataset, check whether any nan is present in the next 12 locations of the dataframe in the column B.

If there are nan, then replace it with the forecast.

How can I do this easily with pandas.?

Comment: In your example, the one to fill in the 2nd row should probably be forecasts[1]? Python's indexing starts at 0.

Comment: @Tai in the list, forecasts[0] will correspond to the value at the current timestamp

Comment: I think you should define `forecasts`. It seems to pop up from nowhere? I think that is the list but...I don't know now.

Comment: Okay, that list is named as forecasts

Comment: Will you want to do this many times to different rows of the df or it will always start at the first row?

Comment: For every timestamps I will have a lists named forecasts of length 12. Where forecasts[0] corresponds to the value of that timestamp's column B and forecasts[11] the 11th timestamp from the current one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

temp=u"""A;B

2018-02-01 00:00:00;5.592860;2.789900
2018-02-01 00:15:00;5.288981;NaN
2018-02-01 00:30:00;5.319665;2.232686
2018-02-01 00:45:00;5.198657;2.236154
2018-02-01 01:00:00;5.018134;2.064312
2018-02-01 01:15:00;5.018134;NaN
"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), sep=";", parse_dates=True)

print (df)
                            A         B
2018-02-01 00:00:00  5.592860  2.789900
2018-02-01 00:15:00  5.288981       NaN
2018-02-01 00:30:00  5.319665  2.232686
2018-02-01 00:45:00  5.198657  2.236154
2018-02-01 01:00:00  5.018134  2.064312
2018-02-01 01:15:00  5.018134       NaN
```

---

```
L = [0.09545173, 0.09946214, 0.10596157]
r = int(len(df) / len(L))
print (r)
2
s = pd.Series(np.tile(np.array(L), r), index=df.index)
print (s)
2018-02-01 00:00:00    0.095452
2018-02-01 00:15:00    0.099462
2018-02-01 00:30:00    0.105962
2018-02-01 00:45:00    0.095452
2018-02-01 01:00:00    0.099462
2018-02-01 01:15:00    0.105962
dtype: float64

df['B'] = df['B'].fillna(s)
print (df)
                            A         B
2018-02-01 00:00:00  5.592860  2.789900
2018-02-01 00:15:00  5.288981  0.099462
2018-02-01 00:30:00  5.319665  2.232686
2018-02-01 00:45:00  5.198657  2.236154
2018-02-01 01:00:00  5.018134  2.064312
2018-02-01 01:15:00  5.018134  0.105962
```

Comment: Let me make things more clear. I will have a dataframe with data like I said the question. There may be misses in the column B but not A. I will have a list of 12 location for each timestamp. The list being named forecast will have the forecasted value of present timestamp in forecasts[0]. I want to loop though each timestamp in the dataset, check whether any nan is present in the next 12 locations of the dataframe in the column B

Comment: @SreeramTP - So there is e.g. 24 rows and need replace first 12 and then 12 rows?

Comment: If there are 24 rows in the actual dataframe, I will loop through it. First i am at timestamp t0, I will have forecast list. I will have to check whether there are nan in next 11 locations. ie t1 to t11. Suppose there is a nan in t5. Then I have to replace it with forecasts[5] in the actual dataframe. Then I will move to timestamp t2 and do the same

Answer (score 1):

OR a one-liner list comprehension:

```
df['B'] = [l[i] if type(v)==type(np.nan) else v for i,v in enumerate(df['B'].tolist())]
```

Answer (score -1):

Well this is the basic issue to handle or work with missing or unknown values.
You can use **fillna()** function to fill missing values with default value that you want.

**e.g:** If df1 is your dataframe containing missing values in multiple columns.

```
for column in df1:
    print("column ",column)
    df1[column] = df1[column].fillna(0.12345)
```

To check **fillna** syntax and example check https://kite.com/python/docs/pandas.core.frame.DataFrame.fillna

You can also use pandas **isna()** function to check where values are missing.